# iFrame NOT be responsive

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive

I'm trying very hard to make a iframe inside a div (appended with javascript) NOT to be responsive on mobile (and I thought it was hard to MAKE it responsive).

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

The HTML code and JS code can be seen on View Code, it's a dead simple minimal basic example.

THE HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Iframe</title>
<style>
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-color: #FFF;
}
h1 {font-family: Arial; font-size: 36px; color: #000;}
#mark {
margin: 0 -.4em;
padding: .1em .4em;
border-radius: .8em .3em;
background: 0 0;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,225,0,.1),rgba(255,225,0,.7) 4%,rgba(255,225,0,.3));
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
box-decoration-break: clone;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<br /><br /><br />
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;"><h1 id="mark">BACON IPSUM</h1></div>
<br />
<div style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; font-family: Arial; font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.5;">
<p>
Bacon ipsum dolor amet fugiat in ham et dolore jerky landjaeger prosciutto pork chicken ut chuck. Cow burgdoggen picanha irure. Ham cillum ut est id pariatur, non duis spare ribs leberkas ribeye. Prosciutto short loin anim eu shankle sirloin drumstick fatback hamburger aliqua nostrud et consequat tenderloin. Enim tenderloin consequat ea short loin, dolore t-bone sunt commodo andouille cillum minim anim veniam prosciutto. Chicken velit anim proident aute minim meatloaf et bresaola consectetur bacon spare ribs strip steak adipisicing reprehenderit.
<br /><br />
Pariatur venison dolore turkey ball tip beef ribs, in esse shank kielbasa jerky meatball dolor in. Swine pancetta picanha andouille, ea landjaeger rump strip steak boudin shank cillum meatball chislic. Dolor shoulder minim ribeye. Short loin tongue jerky flank officia proident fatback tenderloin.
<br /><br />
<center><img src="https://baconipsum.com/wp-content/themes/baconipsum-custom-theme-v2/images/bacon-ipsum-banner-10th-birthday.jpg" border="0" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"/></center>
<br />
Capicola sed kielbasa bacon, cupim in filet mignon short loin beef shank id velit magna. Excepteur dolor turkey consequat aliquip. Pariatur ipsum ham enim. Do sausage pork chop laboris, spare ribs pork occaecat irure in drumstick ut velit. Pig est laboris consectetur esse. Landjaeger spare ribs swine laboris, ex shank meatball duis turkey occaecat short loin cupim salami nostrud non.
<br /><br />
Jerky pork loin irure ea culpa meatloaf swine lorem beef officia sausage t-bone. Fatback eu flank, chicken velit mollit excepteur beef ribs aliqua nostrud do consectetur. Aliquip boudin ipsum incididunt alcatra biltong tri-tip, meatloaf capicola jerky cupim pancetta. Enim fugiat est, pariatur landjaeger kielbasa consectetur. Sed biltong magna quis veniam, buffalo laborum ut lorem adipisicing. Chicken anim bacon minim, leberkas kielbasa turducken fatback ham proident laboris sed nostrud meatloaf boudin. Non swine dolore, salami sunt aute nostrud meatball bacon fatback meatloaf sed officia reprehenderit.
<br /><br />
Flank duis shank landjaeger officia tri-tip beef ribs frankfurter sunt sausage dolore burgdoggen rump drumstick pariatur. Ullamco tongue tail veniam cupim occaecat prosciutto do ball tip tempor consectetur cow. Buffalo landjaeger shoulder pancetta, aliqua elit sint sausage burgdoggen officia aliquip ham est pork chop. Incididunt flank esse deserunt sausage, quis venison pancetta t-bone in kielbasa ut non meatball. Cillum cupidatat drumstick sausage ipsum jerky. Pariatur flank kielbasa, bresaola in do short loin velit meatball tail.
<br /><br />
Does your lorem ipsum text long for something a little meatier? Give our generator a try… it’s tasty!
<br /><br />
Bacon ipsum dolor amet fugiat in ham et dolore jerky landjaeger prosciutto pork chicken ut chuck. Cow burgdoggen picanha irure. Ham cillum ut est id pariatur, non duis spare ribs leberkas ribeye. Prosciutto short loin anim eu shankle sirloin drumstick fatback hamburger aliqua nostrud et consequat tenderloin. Enim tenderloin consequat ea short loin, dolore t-bone sunt commodo andouille cillum minim anim veniam prosciutto. Chicken velit anim proident aute minim meatloaf et bresaola consectetur bacon spare ribs strip steak adipisicing reprehenderit.
<br /><br />
Pariatur venison dolore turkey ball tip beef ribs, in esse shank kielbasa jerky meatball dolor in. Swine pancetta picanha andouille, ea landjaeger rump strip steak boudin shank cillum meatball chislic. Dolor shoulder minim ribeye. Short loin tongue jerky flank officia proident fatback tenderloin.
<br /><br />
<center><img src="https://baconipsum.com/wp-content/themes/baconipsum-custom-theme-v2/images/bacon-ipsum-banner-10th-birthday.jpg" border="0" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"/></center>
<br />
Capicola sed kielbasa bacon, cupim in filet mignon short loin beef shank id velit magna. Excepteur dolor turkey consequat aliquip. Pariatur ipsum ham enim. Do sausage pork chop laboris, spare ribs pork occaecat irure in drumstick ut velit. Pig est laboris consectetur esse. Landjaeger spare ribs swine laboris, ex shank meatball duis turkey occaecat short loin cupim salami nostrud non.
<br /><br />
Hellovideo 2021
</p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js" async></script>

</body>
</html>
```

THE JS:

```
var scope = this;
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "teste";
div.style.width = "500px";
div.style.height = "500px";
div.style.position = "fixed";
div.style.bottom = "20px";
div.style.right = "20px";
div.style.zIndex = "999999999999999;"

div.innerHTML = '<iframe id="wiframe" src="https://braziljournal.com/" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></iframe>';

scope.document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Inside it, a script create and append a div and a iframe inside it.

On desktop, it displays 500px by 500px for width and height.

But on mobile, it's displaying way small size from 500x500. On inspect, it shows 500x500 on the div and on the iframe.

I tried everything that i could to maske it not to be responsive, but well, here i am.

How can i set the div and/or iframe to be not responsive, to be fixed width and height, regardless of the device (even if it breaks the mobile width)?

It seems to me that it'a a case of viewport on the parent page, but i'm creating a widget that needs to be loaded on the parent page with 500x500, not depending of the parent page viewport settings...

Comment: Post the code here and [don't link to any other site.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) Also please don't shout at people, this is rude.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @cloned sorry, i edited the post.

Comment: I doubt your "tests" have any real meaning at this point, because you did not even set the `viewport` meta tag ... which is pretty much the basis of controlling responsive layout on mobile devices. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: @CBroe I've already tested it with the user-scalable=no meta, and of course it's obvious everything do not resize to mobile. What i'm trying to do is to set the div and or iframe to not resize regardless of the meta declaration on this parent page (which the code is pasted by the user, i do not have control over it).

Comment: I was not talking about the `user-scalable=no` part btw., and more the actual specifying of the `width`.

Comment: _"But on mobile, it's displaying a way better size from 500x500. On inspect, it shows 500x500 on the div and on the iframe."_ - I am still not sure I can even make sense of what that is actually supposed to mean.

Comment: Fixed. "Way small size".

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**

```
transform: scale(1);
```

on iframe styling.

**SOLVED.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).